# why return type of operation overloading is sample

Tags: c++, function, overloading, operation

why sample as return type in operation overloading can anyone explain how this code works. why the return type is class itself  whats the use of .x here

```
#include<iostream>
    class sample
    {
    private:
    int x;
    public:
    sample();
    void display();
    friend sample operator+(sample ob3,sample ob4)
    };
    sample::sample()
    {
    x=1;
    }
    void sample::display()
    {
    cout<<x;
    }
    sample sample::operator+(sample ob3,sample ob4)
    {
    sample ob5;
    ob5.x=ob3.x+ob4.x;
    return(ob4);
    }
    int main()
    {
    sample ob1,ob2,ob3;
    ob3=ob1+ob2;
    ob3.display();
    }
```

---

Comment: Well, when you add an `int` to an `int`, the result is an `int`. When you add a `double` to a `double`, the result is a `double`. When you concatenate a `std::string` with a `std::string`, the result is a `std::string`. Why is it surprising that the result of adding a `sample` to a `sample` is a `sample`? What else do you think it should be?

Comment: There's a typo in the implementation of `operator+`. It computes the sum in `obj5`, but doesn't actually return `obj5`. Instead of returning the sum, it returns its second argument unchanged.

Comment: I am struggling to understand the use of .X please tell me how it works .what happens if we don't use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why sample as return type in operation overloading

The return type is `sample` because the author that wrote the operator overload chose to use `sample` as the return type. It is quite typical for binary `operator+` overloads to have the same return type as the type of the operands.

Part of why it is typical is that it follows the example of all corresponding built-in operators which is a good convention to adhere to. When both operands of a built-in `operator+` have the same type (after conversion), the type of the expression is also the same. For example the operands of `1+1` are `int` and the type of the expression is `int` also. In cases where operands have different type (e.g. pointer arithmetic), the resulting type is one of the operand types.

> whats the use of .x here

`.` is an operator to access the member of an object. `x` is a data member of and instance of the class `sample`.

Comment: sample sample::operator+(sample ob3,sample ob4)
    {
    sample ob5;
    ob5.x=ob3.x+ob4.x;
    return(ob4);
    } What if we don't add .x and why return ob4 because ob5 has the sum of other arguments so if not ob5 is returned why such a process

Comment: @nikcodes `why return ob4` It doesn't make much sense. If it was intentional, then only the author can tell you the answer. But I would guess that it was a mistake.